# Hide dropdown options based on date

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress, woocommerce

I am designing a woocommerce wordpress site in which advert space in a magazine is being sold. I have been asked to include an attribute on each product stating a start date but hide the current month plus the month after to stop people buying space and expecting it to start immediately.

I have extracted the HTML in this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wjjq9br0/) for example purposes.

```css
select {
  border-color: #F1F1F1;
  border-top-color: #DDD;
  border-left-color: #DDD;
  background-color: #F9F9F9;
  color: #515151;
  font: 12px Tahoma;
  padding: 8px;
  margin-bottom: 7px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
  -moz-border-radius: 3px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="label"><label for="advert-size">Advert Size</label></td>
      <td class="value">
        <select id="advert-size" class="" name="attribute_advert-size" data-attribute_name="attribute_advert-size" data-show_option_none="yes">
                <option value="">Choose an option</option>
                <option value="Eighth page" class="attached enabled">Eighth page</option>
                <option value="Quarter page (portrait)" class="attached enabled">Quarter page (portrait)</option>
                <option value="Quarter page (landscape)" class="attached enabled">Quarter page (landscape)</option>
                <option value="Half Page (portrait)" class="attached enabled">Half Page (portrait)</option>
                <option value="Half page (landscape)" class="attached enabled">Half page (landscape)</option>
                <option value="Full page (standard)" class="attached enabled">Full page (standard)</option>
                <option value="Full page (premium)" class="attached enabled">Full page (premium)</option>
                <option value="Front cover banner" class="attached enabled">Front cover banner</option>
            </select>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="label"><label for="advert-period">Advert Period</label></td>
      <td class="value">
        <select id="advert-period" class="" name="attribute_advert-period" data-attribute_name="attribute_advert-period" data-show_option_none="yes">                     <option value="">Choose an option</option>
                <option value="1 month" class="attached enabled">1 month</option>
                <option value="3 months (save 10%)" class="attached enabled">3 months (save 10%)</option>
                <option value="6 months (save 15%)" class="attached enabled">6 months (save 15%)</option>
                <option value="12 months (save 20%)" class="attached enabled">12 months (save 20%)</option></select>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="label"><label for="start-month">Start month</label></td>
      <td class="value">
        <select id="start-month" class="" name="attribute_start-month" data-attribute_name="attribute_start-month" data-show_option_none="yes">
            <option value="">Choose an option</option>
            <option value="Jan" class="attached enabled">Jan</option>
            <option value="Feb" class="attached enabled">Feb</option>
            <option value="Mar" class="attached enabled">Mar</option>
            <option value="Apr" class="attached enabled">Apr</option>
            <option value="May" class="attached enabled">May</option>
            <option value="Jun" class="attached enabled">Jun</option>
            <option value="Jul" class="attached enabled">Jul</option>
            <option value="Aug" class="attached enabled">Aug</option>
            <option value="Sep" class="attached enabled">Sep</option>
            <option value="Oct" class="attached enabled">Oct</option>
            <option value="Nov" class="attached enabled">Nov</option>
            <option value="Dec" class="attached enabled">Dec</option></select><a class="reset_variations" href="#" style="visibility: hidden;">Clear</a> </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>

</table>
```

What would be the best way to do this in either JS or PHP?

Comment: Based on the fact that wordpress is developed using PHP, i would be tempted to do it there rather than expose it to the frontend and "remove" it with javascript.

Comment: `What would be the best way to do this in either JS or PHP?` That question is **primarily opinion-based** `Many good questions generate some degree of opinion based on expert experience, but answers to this question will tend to be almost entirely based on opinions, rather than facts, references, or specific expertise.` - Options are generated create the attribute, i.e: `data-start-date="xxx"` then in JS show/hide what you need based on the condition. When you have code you work on, post it here in a [**Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Apologies, I didn't mean would it be best to do it in JS or PHP, I meant to ask what the best way to do it would be and how would I go about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could replace your options list by:

```
<option value="">Choose an option</option>
<?php
for ($m=1; $m<=12; $m++) {
    $currentMonth = date('n');
    $nextMonth = date('n') == 12 ? 1 : date('n') + 1;

    if ($m == $currentMonth || $m == $nextMonth) continue;

    $month = date('M', mktime(0,0,0,$m, 1, date('Y')));

    echo '<option value="'.$month.'" class="attached enabled">'.$month.'</option>';
}
?>
```

This provides the same list of options you've posted, minus the current and next month.

[PHP Sandbox](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/bb58bbe53edc1e125d06ee5f8ddd4b218a015afc)

Answer (score 0):

As I said, i'd do it in `PHP`. You will need to find out which the current month is and don't add an `option` in the list for this or the next month. You can use something like:

```
<?php
    $months = array("Jan", "Feb", ..., "Dec");
    $thismonth = date('M');
    $date = date("Y-m-d");
    $date = strtotime(date("Y-m-d", strtotime($date)) . " +1 month");
    $nextmonth = date("M",$date);
    foreach ($months as $month) :
        if ($month != $thismonth && $month != $nextmonth):
            echo "<option value=\"" . $month . "\">" . $month . "</option>";
        endif;
    endforeach
?>
```